# Access variables in the actionPerformed

Tags: java, java-ee-6, actionlistener

I have to define a variable called 'path' as can be seen in the code inside the ActionListener...but I can not access 'path' variable outside the actionPerformed method! It becomes null outside the method...How can i access this variable?!

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.println("Search " + textField.getText()
                    + " in Project");

            try {
                System.out.println(project.members().length);
                IResource[] ires = project.members();
                String path = "";
                String findResult = "notFound";
                for (int len = 0; len < ires.length; len++) {
                    if (!(path = loopInFolders(project, ires[len],
                            textField.getText())).equals("")) {
                        System.out.println("found at :" + path);
                        findResult = "found";

                        showResultBox(findResult, path);

                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (path.equals("")) {
                    showResultBox(findResult, path);
                }
            } catch (CoreException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
```

Even I defined the variable as global variable in the class with getter and setter..but the variable does not keep its value which it has inside actionPerformed! Only inside the Listener has the correct value which i want...I want to use this value in other methods, but it becomes null there!

This is my class! I want to access the path variable in execute method, this variable will be filled in actionListener inside createOutput method, but it is always null outside the actionListener!

```
public class FindHandler extends AbstractHandler {

private String path;

@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

    Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event);
    ISelection sel = HandlerUtil.getActiveMenuSelection(event);

    IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    IProject project = root.getProject(sel.toString()
            .substring(1, sel.toString().indexOf(" ")).trim());
    System.out.println("selected folder "
            + sel.toString().substring(1, sel.toString().indexOf(" "))
                    .trim());



    createOutput(shell, project);

    if (path != null) {
        System.out.println("Pathhhh***444"+ path);
        IPath iPath = new Path(path);
        IFile file = project.getFile(iPath);
        System.out.println("test file*****" + file.getName());

        file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
                .getFileForLocation(iPath);

        ISelection selection = new StructuredSelection(file);

        IViewReference[] views = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
                .getViewReferences();
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
                .getActivePage().resetPerspective();

        for (IViewReference view : views) {
            if ("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer".equals(view.getId())) {
                IViewPart pExplorer = view.getView(true);
                pExplorer.getViewSite().getSelectionProvider()
                        .setSelection(selection);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private void createOutput(Shell shell, final IProject project) {

    // Creating the window with a textBox and two buttons of 'Search' and
    // 'Cancel'
    System.out.println(project.getLocation());
    final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Search File");
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(350, 250);
    frame.setLocation(350, 250);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter File Name:");
    label.setSize(120, 20);
    label.setLocation(20, 25);
    textField.setSize(150, 20);
    textField.setLocation(150, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
    JButton button = new JButton("Search");
    button.setSize(100, 30);
    button.setLocation(70, 100);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.println("Search " + textField.getText()
                    + " in Project");

            try {
                System.out.println(project.members().length);
                IResource[] ires = project.members();
                path = "";
                String findResult = "notFound";
                for (int len = 0; len < ires.length; len++) {
                    if (!(path = loopInFolders(project, ires[len],
                            textField.getText())).equals("")) {
                        System.out.println("found at :" + path);
                        findResult = "found";

                        showResultBox(findResult, path);

                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (path.equals("")) {
                    showResultBox(findResult, path);
                }
            } catch (CoreException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(button); // Adds Button to content pane of
                                        // frame
    JButton button_2 = new JButton("Cancel");
    button_2.setSize(100, 30);
    button_2.setLocation(180, 100);
    button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            frame.dispose();
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(button_2);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

    System.out.println("Pathhhh***333"+ path);

}


public String loopInFolders(IProject project, IResource ires,
        String fileName) {

    if (ires.getName().equals(fileName)) {
        return ires.getLocation().toString();
    } else {
        System.out.println(ires.getName());
        IFolder secondFolder = null;
        try {
            secondFolder = project.getFolder(ires.getName());
            System.out.println(secondFolder.members().length);
            if (secondFolder.members().length > 0) {
                IResource[] ires1 = secondFolder.members();
                for (int i = 0; i < ires1.length; i++) {
                    if (!loopInFolders(project, ires1[i], fileName).equals(
                            ""))
                        return ires1[i].getLocation().toString();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
    return "";

}

public void showResultBox(String findResult, String path) {

    if (findResult.equals("notFound")) {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Not Found");
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(350, 250);
        frame.setLocation(350, 250);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("There is no such file in the project!");
        label.setSize(600, 20);
        label.setLocation(20, 25);

        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

    } else {

        System.out.println("Pathhhh***111"+ path);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Found");
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(350, 250);
        frame.setLocation(350, 250);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("File is found at: " + path);
        label.setSize(600, 20);
        label.setLocation(20, 25);

        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Of course you can't. Its locale variable. Make it as an instance (put it outside of your method).

Answer (score 3):

```
    // make path a global variable
    String path;


    // if you are trying to access path in another class,
    // make sure you have a getter method like 
    public String getPath() {
       return this.path;
    }

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        System.out.println("Search " + textField.getText()
                + " in Project");

        try {
            System.out.println(project.members().length);
            IResource[] ires = project.members();
            path = "";
            String findResult = "notFound";
            for (int len = 0; len < ires.length; len++) {
                if (!(path = loopInFolders(project, ires[len],
                        textField.getText())).equals("")) {
                    System.out.println("found at :" + path);
                    findResult = "found";

                    showResultBox(findResult, path);

                    break;
                }
            }

            if (path.equals("")) {
                showResultBox(findResult, path);
            }
        } catch (CoreException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, I did this, even I defined getter and setter for it..but what i meant was that the 'path' variable does not keep its value which it has inside actionPerformed! Only inside the Listener has the correct value which i want...I want to use this value in other methods, but it will become null there!

Comment: @OrclUser No, you didn't.  Have a look at the differences between your `actionPerformed` method and Jane's.  Then read the comments left in my question

Comment: Did you make sure to take the 'String' out just in front of your 'path' variable inside the actionPerformed?

Comment: i have spent two days in solving this issue but now i fixed that. Thank you @JaneDoh

Answer (score 2):

Declare a class level field called `path`.  In your `ActionListener`, DO NOT redeclare it again, simply assign the new value you need to it.

```
public class MyClass {
    private String path;

    public MyClass() {
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                path = "";                
                //....//
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is a simplified example, your implementation may be different...

Comment: Actually, I did this, even I defined getter and setter for it..but what i meant was that the 'path' variable does not keep its value which it has inside actionPerformed! Only inside the Listener has the correct value which i want...I want to use this value in other methods, but it will become null there!

Comment: That's because you're re-decalred path as a local variable, it's value will only have meaning within the context of the `actionPerforemd` method.  In you `actionPerformed` method, change `String path = "";` to `path = "";`

Comment: @OrclUser: actually you didn't do this, else it would work. 1+ to mad programmer. Please read up on "variable shadowing" because that's what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may also be that you're using a JFrame instead of a modal JDialog. Your execute method creates a window (the JFrame mentioned above), displays the window and then ***immediately*** tries to use the path variable, before the use has had any chance to interact with the new window, so it makes sense that path would be null.

To prevent this from happening, to stop the execution of the execute method until the user has handled the window and pressed the key JButton, again don't display a JFrame but rather a JDialog that is modal. If you do this, when the dialog is set to visible, the calling code is put on "hold" until the dialog is no longer visible, at which time with luck path won't be null.

Comment: @OrclUser: that is one version of a modal dialog, so wonderful and congrats!

Comment: tnx..how can I customize buttons in JoptionPane?

Comment: This : String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter File Name:"); only gives me the Ok and Cancel buttons..i want to have search instead of Ok!

Comment: Take a look at [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) instead then